# jenkins 2.7 pipeline build in docker container

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I am trying to build my project with Jenkins and pipeline plugin in docker container. My `Jenkinsfile` looks like this:

```
node('docker') {
    docker.image('build-node:1').inside {
        stage 'scm checkout'
        checkout scm

        stage 'maven build'
        sh "mvn -B clean > mvn.log"
    }
}
```

In Jenkins log:

```
...
Entering stage maven build
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[versioning] Running shell script
+ mvn -B clean
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop ***
$ docker rm -f ***
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -1
Finished: FAILURE
```

In mvn.log I see all is ok:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: X.XXX s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-XX-XXTXX:XX:XX+XX:XX
[INFO] Final Memory: XXM/XXXM
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where is an error or how determine it?

My Jenkins server is docker container form docker hub, which using docker server as a node.

New check:

```
try {
    sh 'mvn clean | tee mvn.log'
} catch (e) {
    println "Maven failed : ${e}"
}
```

Output:

```
[versioning] Running shell script
+ mvn clean
+ tee mvn.log
[Pipeline] echo
Maven failed : hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code -1
```

mvn.log:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configure pipeline on 1651.3 LTS version of Jenkins and all work perfect. I think problem was in combination of plugins or unstable core version of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
sh 'mvn -B clean | tee mvn.log'
```

so that you can see the output from Maven in the build log. Or simply

```
sh 'mvn -B clean'
```

if you were not planning on using `mvn.log` for anything anyway.

Comment: Command sh 'mvn -B clean' have no logs in Jenkins logs, same as in question.

Comment: I add  "> mvn.log" to build command to understand whats going on.

Comment: Jenkins 2.8 same problem

Comment: Jenkins 2.9 and 1.651.2 same problem